# can not output value from session

Tags: php

i have 3 php files
1st: named as 'test.php'

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user'])){
header('Location:index-an.php');
}
else{
echo 'pls input';
}

?>
<form action='#' method='post'>
user <input type='text' name='user'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

second named as 'core-an.php'

```
<?php
session_start();
function loggedin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
?>
```

third named as 'index-an.php'

```
<?php
require 'core-an.php';
if(loggedin())
{
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
echo 'hello '.$user.' have a nice day';
}
else
{
include 'test.php';
}

?>
```

When i input the value and press submit, It doesn't output anything.

Comment: You're not saving anything into `$_SESSION` in your `test.php` file before you redirect to `index-an.php`. Try doing `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];` before the redirect and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Try putting `session_start();` in every file.

Comment: what is that '#' doing in `action`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there are no ways in which, your `$_POST` array is being assigned to `$_SESSION['user']`

So, In your `test.php` file, modify your PHP code to this:

```
 session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user'])){
   $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    header('Location:index-an.php');
  }else{
    echo 'pls input';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value to the $_SESSION['user'] variable. Hence, the else statement is executed. So, instead of redirecting to the same page again, redirect it to a test page  where you actually assign the `username` to the `$_SESSION['user']` variable. So do it like this:

**test.php**

```
<form action='random.php' method='post'>
user <input type='text' name='user'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

**random.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']
header('Location: /test.php');
```

Comment: Thank alot .I felt like a chimp when i realized my mistake.